# Change Size Of Next Page Pagination In Posts

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to ask, how can I change size of post pagination which has code 
--nextpage--

I tried this code:

```
.td-post-content .page-nav a {
font-size: 16px;
}
```

But it does not work...
Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you post your html  too?

Answer (score 0):

Your style is being added to the class attribute of the body tag not in a stylesheet, style element, or style attribute.

[image]

To fix this you will need to remove the style from the location it is in now and find an appropriate stylesheet, style element, or style attribute to add it to.

Checkout this article to help you get started [Finding Your CSS Styles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Finding_Your_CSS_Styles).